# where is my hdd space

Tags: hard-drive, partition, disk-space-utilization, centos8

I am new to linux and installed Centos with default configuration without applying any custom settings, while I have 512 GB SSD drive but on gnome it shows only 75 gb, when I tried to run fdisk command it shows some partition but I dont see them on UI (see screenshots)

[Disk on CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix8qP.png)

[Disk on UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW2uM.png)

so can someone tell me there is that big partition, how can I use it, and can I increase space in partition being shown as I have placed my data there and now its almost full, and if I run some data operations I get warning of disk full.

Answer (score 0):

Your disk layout is done using LVM it is a Logical Volume Manager, you can use it to dynamically change the layout of the partitions during system operation (resizing, creating new volumes, creating snapshots for backup etc.)

The lower part of what you have pasted show a `home` LV that is 387GB long.
I suppose that when you type `df -h` in CLI you will see that your total disk space sums to your disk size, but is dispersed among a few mountpoints and not allocated to only one of them.

the `lsblk` command will also show you the layout in some more friendly way

You need to rethink on what layout would you like to have and perhaps it will be easier for you to reinstall the OS paying attention to the layout this time (centos 8 installer has a nice gui that allows you to adjust the layout during installation)
Shrinking the partitions now is a good practice if you are interested in Linux mor than just using it. But might be somewhat unfriendly.
LVM is managed through commands :
`vgdisplay` - shows volume groups
`lvdisplay` - shows logical volumes
`lvcreate` - creates new volumes
`resize2fs` - resizes filesystems so you can reduce partition size (can destroy data)
`lvresize` - resizes volumes
`lvremove` - removes logica volumes (deletes data)

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer which is really helpful, but as I mentioned I am very new to Linux, can you just tell me simple commands to shrink the Home LV of 387GB and use that space to increase in my localhost root one, as this is our local web server, and that 70 Gb partition contains all web files.

Comment: as I said the simplest is to reinstall, doing it manually is much more complicated
it might not be always possible to shirnk the partitions, sometimes you just need to remove them and removing `/home` on a running system without moving it somewhere else first will most likely brick the machine